# How to find the mean of $X^3$ if $X$ is standard normal distributed

Tags: probability, statistics

I managed to find the PDF of $X^3$ given $X$~$N(0,1)$:

$Y=X^3$ then for any $y$, $P(0<X^3<y)= \phi (\sqrt[3]{y}) - \phi (0)$ and then derivate that to find $f_Y(y)$. But that didn't give me anything. I know that to find the mean of a function of a variable, in this case I will need to calculate the integral on the PDF of normal distributy which is very hard. So what is the other way?

Comment: Hint: the integral in this case has an odd integrand whose integral on $[0,\,\infty)$ converges (you needn't compute it).

Comment: The moment generating function of $N(0,1)$ is $e^{-\frac12t^2}$ which implies that $E[X^n] = 0$ for odd $n$ and $E[X^n] =\frac{n!}{2^{n/2} \,\left(\frac n2\right)!}$ for even $n$: [OEIS A123023](https://oeis.org/A123023)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $X\sim N(0,1)$, the support of $Y=X^3$ is $\mathbb{R}$. Now, if we denote by $\Phi$ the cdf of $X$, we have $$f_Y(y)=(F_Y(y))'=(\Phi(\sqrt[3]{y}))'=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{y^2}}f_X(\sqrt[3]{y})$$

As $X$ is symettric, $f_X(\sqrt[3]{y})=f_X(\sqrt[3]{-y})$ and so $f_Y(y)=f_Y(-y)$. Thus, $Y$ is symettric and so $\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$, where we have used that $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ exists.

This can be generalized as follows: if $Z$ is a symettric (about $0$) random variable, then for every $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ odd, if $\mathbb{E}[Z^k]$ exists it must be equal to $0$. The condition that the expected value exists is needed: a Cauchy distribution is symettric but its mean does not exist.